# Does mutex and semaphores "Busy wait" in a LINUX systems?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, mutex, semaphore, thread-synchronization

Recently I came to know that **Sleep** system call in a linux kernel will suspend the current calling thread to a **suspended/blocked** state, meaning they wont utilise the CPU until the mentioned time elapse. - *perfectly understood*.

Now coming to mutex and semaphores,

Mutex Locks:

```
acquire() {
while (!available)
; // busy wait    --> my doubt
available = false;;
}

release() {
available = true;
}
```

Semaphore locks:

```
wait(S) {
while (S <= 0)
; // busy wait --> my doubt
S--;
}
signal(S) {
S++;
}
```

P.S: these code snippets are taken from *"operating systems concepts -9th edition"* by ABRAHAM SILBERSCHATZ

**My question:**

I know that busy wait is not an efficient way to approach synchronisation problems, but from the code snippets mentioned above i got a doubt that  using mutex and semaphores will end up in a **busy wait** ?? (*though mutexes and semaphores being widely used to solve most sysnc problems*).

**Which inturn make me feel that using mutex & semaphores is not an efficient way to solve sync problems as it is going to consume CPU cycles** *(because it will not lead to suspended state rather spinning in a while loop )*.

*To be short :* **Does mutexes and semaphores busy waits rather putting the waiting thread thread to a suspended state ??**

Thanks in advance !!. Kindly correct me if am wrong in my understanding !!

Comment: The short answer is yes and no, but it's more complicated than your book describes.  Take a loot at [semaphores](https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/SyncPrim/sync-3.html) and [mutexes](https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/SyncPrim/sync-4.html).  The longer form is that if the mutex or semaphore is acquired, then it will park the calling thread until the primitive has been released.  This is much better that just spinning--and you're absolutely correct, if it was just spinning it would be very inefficient.  Fortunately, it's not. :-)

Comment: @jszakmeister Not just inefficient, it would be broken!

Comment: @curiousguy very true!

Comment: @jszakmeister : i guess i got mislead by the code snippet in the book that says a line "busy wait"..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does mutexes and semaphores busy waits

No, internally those functions (e.g. Pthread mutexes functions like `pthread_mutex_lock`) use [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability) machine instructions (coded in assembler) coupled with [futex(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/futex.7.html).

For POSIX semaphores (see [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html)) the kernel [scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)#SCHEDULER) would schedule other tasks. So it is not busy waiting.

If no task is runnable, the kernel would sit in its [idle loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idle_(CPU)) waiting (without burning CPU cycles) for something (like an [interrupt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt)). So your laptop won't overheat and use too much battery in such case!

Read also [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (freely downloadable). Look also on [OSDEV](http://osdev.org/) if you want to develop some toy kernel.  You could also study the source code of the Linux [kernel](http://kernel.org/) since it is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) then ask on [kernelnewbies](http://kernelnewbies.org/). The standard C library and its pthread layer is also free software (so study [GNU glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) source code).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i guess i got mislead by the code snippet in the book that says a line " // busy wait".

Comment: When someone write a book with C code snippet, he can't express wait in plain C. He'll write some comment instead. But the "busy" word is confusing in your book.